# Accessing remote folders when vpn is connected failed

Tags: windows-7, vpn, shared-folders

I have a computer that is connected to a remote computer via VPN. 
When the VPN connection is up I'm unable to connect to remote shared folders from other local computers defined in my domain (LAN).
Why is that?

Comment: It seems to be users related (VPN is defined on all users) in one user everything is OK (I can reach shared folder) but when I switch to a different user (VPN is on the entire time) I'm unable to reach (both users are domain admins).

Answer (score 0):

From [Microsoft Support](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317025)

This occur if you configure the VPN connection to use the default gateway on the remote network. This setting overrides the default gateway settings that you specify in your Transmission Control Protocol/Internet Protocol (TCP/IP) settings.

So This is the default design of VPN. If you want to access LAN/Internet and VPN simultaneously

- Go to properties of VPN.
- Click on the Networking tab and double click Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4).
- Click Advanced and uncheck the box for "Use default gateway on remote network.".

  [image]

  This will route all of your local traffic through network you're locally connected, and remote traffic through the VPN assuming that you are not trying to route your internet traffic through the VPN.

Comment: "Use default gateway on remote network." was already disable (double checked right now)